# Как создать свой div для каждого элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно посчитать количество .romb и для каждого создать отдельный div.

```
<div class="rombs">
    <div class="romb1"></div>
    <div class="romb2"></div>
    <div class="romb3"></div>
    <div class="romb4"></div>
    <div class="romb5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: что за разметка в вопросе? исходная или которая должна в итоге получиться?

Comment: Понятнее опишите вопрос , и что должно быть на выходе (создать отдельный div  (куда..))

Comment: А зачем их считать надо? Какая конечная цель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаем кол-во блоков и внутри каждого помещаем div:

```js
var rombs = $('.rombs [class^="romb"]');
var rombsNum = rombs.length;

$.each(rombs, function(index, val) {
  $(this).html('<div></div>');
});
    
alert('Кол-во: ' + rombsNum);
```

```css
.rombs > div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.rombs div div {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:10px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rombs">
    <div class="romb1"></div>
    <div class="romb2"></div>
    <div class="romb3"></div>
    <div class="romb4"></div>
    <div class="romb5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: твой код можно упростить до: `$('.rombs [class^="romb"]').html('<div></div>'});`

Comment: @Grundy, да, можно и так. Только там опечатка, `}` лишняя.

Comment: Да, от другого варианта осталось